# Real numbers is MySQL

Tags: mysql, floating-point, compare

Should I take precaution when comparing real numbers in MySQL?

```
# Get completly paid bills
select * from bills left join payments on bills.id = payments.bill
         where bills.price = payments.price;
```

In usual programming languages (like C/C++), such comparisions between real numbers (floats) must be done using a `delta` value acting as comparision precision:

if (abs(bill_price - payments_bill) < 0.00001)
      // do something

But I don't know if MySQL has such precision problems.

Comment: If it's a `FLOAT` datatype, it has the same problems as any other software that uses floating point.

Comment: Using floating point for monetary data is generally a bad idea, use `DECIMAL` instead.

Comment: @Barmar It was just a fast example.

Comment: I have been using int for money * 100, and no problem :)

Comment: @Barmar not that it matters, but more precisely `REAL` is a synonym for `DOUBLE` unless `REAL_AS_FLOAT` mode is set

Comment: @darw I thought we were talking about all floating point datatypes, not specifically REAL. And they all have the same problems of inability to represent decimals precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's internal floating point format is 64-bit IEEE.

Yes, you need to worry about [machine epsilon (roundoff errors)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) when doing that kind of arithmetic in MySQL.